# What credentials should I use to allow the users to upload directly to GCS?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am making an application in GAE (python) which allows users (who must be logged in with a Google Account) to upload files to Google Cloud Storage directly. The upload would happen asynchronously (a button would execute some javascript code to send the XHR PUT request with the file).

I decided to use the [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/), and I'm trying to do a multipart upload. According to the docs I need to include an Authorization header with a token. I was wondering, since I don't need access to anything in the user's account (like calendar or that kind of thing), what would be the best way to achieve this?

Is it possible to create a temporary access token from the application default credentials and send that to the user within the html file to use it then from the js function? If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to ask the user to grant you the google cloud storage write scopes (which I would strongly recommend any google cloud storage user not grant to any random application).  You would also need to grant the end users write permission on your bucket (which also means they can delete everything in the bucket).  Unless you know all of your end users up front, this means you would need to make the bucket public write.. which I doubt is something you want to do.

I strongly recommend using delegating access to your service account instead, though unfortunately the JSON api does not currently support any form of authentication delegation.  However, the XML API does support Signed URLs.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

You only need to use it for the client-side uploads, everything else can use the JSON api.

There are three options:

1. Just sign a simple PUT request

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object-upload#query_string_parameters

2. Use a form POST and sign a policy document

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#policydocument

3. Initiate a resumable upload server side and pass the upload URL back to the client.  I would only recommend this option if being able to resume the upload is important (e.g. large uploads).

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls#signing-resumable

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer, I just got time to see this. I'll read all the docs that you just posted and get back to you with some results. Thanks!

Comment: You are right, this is the way to do it. Now I'm having trouble with signed urls ("The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.") but that is another problem that I have to solve. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a [python library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage-blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.generate_signed_url) for signing URLs that you might find helpful.

Comment: Yes, that's the one I'm using now. It does most of the work. Thanks.